# i couldn't add python to my path using GIT And it is not working on my windows 10. this is my line of code below

Tags: python, git, python-requests, anaconda, python-3.7

```
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 /usr/bin
$ conda --version
conda 4.7.12
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 /usr/bin
$ cd
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/Aanuoluwa
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 ~
$  echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3/Scripts"' >> .bashrc
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 ~
$ echo 'alias python="winpty python.exe"' >> .bashrc
Aanuoluwa@AANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 ~
$ source .bashrc
bash: export PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3/Scripts": No such file or directory
bash: alias python="winpty python.exe": command not found
Aanuoluwa@strong textAANUOLUWA-PC MINGW64 ~
$
```

Comment: `$PATH:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3:/c/Users/Aanuoluwa/Anaconda3/Scripts` It seems to be invalid. Either of the last 2 directories do not exist in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try the opposite quotes scheme:

```
echo "alias python='winpty python.exe'">>.bashrc
```

So double quotes outside, simple quotes inside.